# Custom ModelForm with FormHelper re-appends buttons Div after each refresh when a layout is passed

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

To keep my `ModelForm`s DRY I have created a custom `ModelForm` with a `FormHelper` so I can append a `Div` with a `Submit` and a `Cancel` button to the `layout`. It also offers the possibility to add a custom layout.

This works perfectly fine when I don't specify a custom layout, but when I do, every time I refresh the page it appends the buttons `Div` (this doesn't happen when there's no custom layout)

This is the custom `ModelForm`:

```py
class ModelFormWithHelper(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs = self.get_helper_kwargs()
        helper_class = FormHelper(self)
        if 'custom_layout' in kwargs:
            self.helper.layout = kwargs['custom_layout']
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-12'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-12'
        self.helper.layout.append(
            Div(
                HTML('<br>'),
                FormActions(
                    Submit('submit', 'Save'),
                    HTML('<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERRER }}">Cancel</a>')
                ),
                css_class='row justify-content-center',
            ),
        )

    def get_helper_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = {}
        for attr, value in self.Meta.__dict__.items():
            if attr.startswith('helper_'):
                new_attr = attr.split('_', 1)[1]
                kwargs[new_attr] = value
        return kwargs
```

And this is the `ModelForm`:

```py
class CargoForm(ModelFormWithHelper):
    class Meta:
        model = Cargo
        exclude = []
        helper_custom_layout = Layout(
            Div(
                'name',
                'order',
                css_class='col-6 offset-3',
            ),
        )
```

This is the form with no custom_layout after I refresh the page 3 times:
[image: form with no custom_layout]

And this is the form with a custom_layout after I refresh the page 3 times:
[image]

I'm aware that I can use the `self.helper.add_input` method to avoid this problem, but then I would not be able to center de buttons.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me solve this re-appending problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the `add_layout` method?

Comment: Hello @DanielHolmes, yes, but the result is sadly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost having a mental breakdown, I have finally figured it out.

For anyone trying to achieve the same goal, here's the solution (I got rid of the `get_helper_kwargs` method since I only use `helper_custom_layout`)

```py
# Put it in a variable to avoid repeating it twice
buttons_layout = Layout(
    Div(
        HTML('<br>'),
        FormActions(
            Submit('submit', 'Save'),
            HTML('<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">Cancel</a>')
        ),
        css_class='row justify-content-center',
    ),
)


class ModelFormWithHelper(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        custom_layout = getattr(self.Meta, 'helper_custom_layout', None)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-12'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-12'
        if custom_layout:
            self.helper.layout = Layout(custom_layout, buttons_layout)
        else:
            self.helper.layout.append(buttons_layout)
```

And that's it. Now you can make your custom `Layout`s a little bit more DRY. Hope you can find this useful.